# Python - How to filter column mix with int and string using DataFrame.query()?

Tags: python

I would like to filter records based on some criteria as below:

```
import pandas as pd
def doFilter(df, type, criteria):
    if type=="contain":
        return df[df.country.apply(str).str.contains(criteria)]
    elif type=="start":
        return df[df.remarks.apply(str).str.startswith(criteria)]

df= pd.read_csv("testdata.csv")
tempdf = doFilter(df, "contain", "U")
finaldf = doFilter(tempdf, "start", "123")
print(finaldf)
```

[testdata.csv]

```
id   country   remarks
1    UK        123
2    UK        123abc
3    US        456
4    JP        456
```

[Output]

```
   id     country   remarks
0   1     UK        123
1   2     UK        123abc
```

As I need to filter dynamically by reading input config for different criteria (e.g. startswith(), contains(), endswith(), substring() etc.), I would like to use DataFrame.query() so that I can filter everything in 1 go.

e.g.

I've tried many ways similar to below but no luck:

```
output=df.query('country.apply(str).str.contains("U") & remarks.apply(str).str.startswith("123")')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Query does not work with callable methods, I would suggest placing an `if statement` and hard coding the filter in different scenarios, i.e. `if filtertype = 'start': #... .str.startswith(...`

Comment: Hi RichieV, thank you so much for your suggestion. Instead of creating temp DataFrame,Is there a way to that I can filter for different criteria in one go?

Comment: Thanks RichieV. I've further updated my question.

Comment: yes, my needs is similar to pass system arguments. I need to create the filter at run time. I will need to read a set of different filter criteria from database. The above is just a simplified version. I have dataset with more than 10miilion records. so, I cannot hardcode and performance is a concern and that's why I avoid create too many temp. dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not test since you provide no sample data.

This will allow you to read filters at runtime and apply them with pandas built-in string methods.

```
# better to cast all relevant columns to string while setting up
df.country = df.country.astype(str)
df.remarks = df.remarks.astype(str)

# get passed filters
filter1 = [ # (field, filtertype, value, jointype)
    ('country', 'contains', 'U'),
    ('remarks', 'startswith', '123'),
]

# create a collection of boolean masks
mask = []
for field, filtertype, value in filter1:
    if filtertype == 'contains':
        mask.append(df[field].str.contains(value))
    elif filtertype == 'startswith':
        mask.append(df[field].str.startswith(value))
    elif filtertype == 'endswith':
        mask.append(df[field].str.startswith(value))

# all these filters need to be combined with `and`, as in `condition1 & condition2`
# if you need to allow for `or` then the whole thing gets a lot more complicated
# as you also need to expect parenthesis as in `(cond1 | cond2) & cond3`
# but it can be done with a parser

# allowing only `and` conditions
mask_combined = mask[0]
form m in mask[1:]:
    mask_combined *= m

# apply filter
df_final = df[mask_combined]
```

Comment: @SBSiuBo You are welcome, it would have been easier to answer if you explained your situation in more detail, showing the source and structure of the filters, I hope this works

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much, RichieV. I've also changed *= to &=.

Comment: @SBSiuBo if you ever write the implementation for `cond1 or cond2`, do let me know